# Reuse created controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a TableLayoutPanel with 2 columns. (first column will contain the field name and the other the field value)

```
Label lbl = new Label {
    AutoSize = false,
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
    TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
};

TextBox txt = new TextBox{
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
    ReadOnly = true,
};
```

So I have this controls created and what I want to do is to reuse them in order to insert data into table .

```
lbl.Text = "field1";
txt.Text = "value1";
tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(lbl,0,0)
tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(txt,1,0)

lbl.Text = "field2";
txt.Text = "value2";
tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(lbl,0,1)
tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(txt,1,1)
```

This doesn't work. It will add only field2 and value2 . Even if I set lbl.name = "smt" and then lbl.name = "smtElse" it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reuse controls in that way. Each time you create a control (eg. `new Label(…)`) that creates a unique object that can only exist once in parent window (or other container control). If you change its properties (including placing it in another container) it will update (including moving) that control.

To place two instances of a control you need to create two instances of that control.